# Play sound continuously when button is pressed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, audio, phonegap

Is there any way of playing a sound/audio file continuously (**using JavaScript**) when a button (HTML) is pressed ?

i.e., as long as the button is pressed, the sound plays - once lifted the sound stops.

I've got the sound to play onclick - but obviously it stops after x amount of seconds.

Is there any way to keep it playing until lifted ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use the `mousedown` event and `mouseup` event

Comment: If you're using an <audio> element, you can add the `loop` attribute, as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). Otherwise, please post the relevant source code.

Comment: Cheers @CertainPerformance - that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like below:

```
<button onmousedown="playVid()" onmouseup="pauseVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
```

**Code snippet:**

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
   vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
   vid.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <body>
      <button onmousedown="playVid()" onmouseup="pauseVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
      <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
         <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
         Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
      <p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can try this with this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause).

Comment: Thanks @imEnCoded - Attaching it to a mousedown event worked

Comment: Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener